# SwiftUIのボタンなどを動的に追加したのですが、その方法がわかりません。

Tags: swift, swiftui

### 質問

SwiftUIのボタンなどを動的に追加したのですが、その方法がわかりません。

やりたい動きとしては、上のボタンで、値変更
下のボタンで、新たにボタン(UI)を追加するといったものです。

### UI

[image]

### コード

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Climate: View {
    @State var humid = 67
    @State var temperature = 76
    @State var lightness = 45
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ClimateData("照度", lightness)
            ClimateData("温度", temperature)
            ClimateData("湿度", humid)
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    self.humid = 123
                }, label: {
                Text("湿度変更")
            })
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    // 新たなClimateDataを追加
                }, label: {
                Text("新たなClimateDataを追加")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct Climate_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Climate()
    }
}

struct ClimateData: View {
    @State var name: String
    @State var value: Int
    
    init(_ name: String, _ value: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(name)
            Text((String(value)))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUIはUIを宣言的に表現すること、つまりview階層もソースコード中に「宣言」的に現すことを目指したUIフレームワークですので、ボタンなどのUI要素を任意のview階層に動的に追加することは出来ません。

UIKitでは簡単に出来ていたことですが、SwiftUIでアプリを作るのであれば発想を変える(もしかしたら提供するアプリの機能そのものを見直す)必要があるでしょう。

「ボタンなど」と書かれていて、どんな機能のボタンなのか、ボタン以外にどんなものを想定しているのかがわからないので、あまり実用的な例は書けませんが、例えば次のようなことなら可能です。

```
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let action: ()->Void
}

struct Climate: View {
    @State var humid = 67
    @State var temperature = 76
    @State var lightness = 45
    
    @State var buttonItems: [ButtonItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ClimateData("照度", lightness)
            ClimateData("温度", temperature)
            ClimateData("湿度", humid)
            
            ForEach(buttonItems) { item in
                Button(
                    action: item.action,
                    label: {
                        Text(item.title)
                })
            }
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    self.buttonItems.append(
                        ButtonItem(
                            title: "温度変更",
                            action: {
                            self.temperature = 100
                        })
                    )
                }, label: {
                Text("新たなClimateDataを追加")
            })
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.buttonItems.append(
                ButtonItem(
                    title: "湿度変更",
                    action: {
                    self.humid = 123
                })
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UIKitのaddSubview()的なことは出来なくなったんですね。